# Как объединить два блока из формы в одну строку?

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

.По дефолту форма заполняется через строку, а нужно в одну.
Пример: Имя Фамилия

Возможно ли без CSS?

Код:

```
<?php if ($config_fields['f_name']['display']){?>
        <div>
            <label class="name">
                <?php echo _JSHOP_FULL_NAME; ?> <?php if ($config_fields['l_name']['require'].' '.$config_fields['f_name']['require']){?><span>*</span><?php } ?>
            </label>
            <span class="input">
                <input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name" value="" class="inputbox" />
            </span>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>    

        <?php if ($config_fields['l_name']['display']){?>
        <div>
            <label class="name">
                <?php echo _JSHOP_L_NAME; ?> <?php if ($config_fields['l_name']['require']){?><span>*</span><?php } ?>
            </label>
            <span class="input">
                <input type="text" name="l_name" id="l_name" value="" class="inputbox" />
            </span>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: ну дак отредактируйте разметку то, в чем проблема?

Comment: @teran я пытался в один div все засунуть, но с условием php косячу. через <?php if ($config_fields['l_name']['display'] and $config_fields['f_name']['display']){?> пытался, но ошибку выдает

Comment: Может nobr поможет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разберите код, который я написал, т.к. если вы пишите `php` код в `html` вам следует использовать другую схему написания, также почитайте про [Краткую запись кода](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), которую уместно использовать в данном случае. Вообще не понятно что у вас проверяется внутри условия `if` в имени, может вы пропустили логическое И (`&&`) между строками? .

```html
<div>
  <?php if ($config_fields['f_name']['display']): ?>
    <label class="name">
      <?= _JSHOP_FULL_NAME . ($config_fields['l_name']['require'].' '.$config_fields['f_name']['require']) ? '<span>*</span>' : '' ?>
      <input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name" value="" class="inputbox" />
    </label>
  <?php endif: ?>
    
  <?php if ($config_fields['l_name']['display']): ?>
    <label class="name">
      <?= _JSHOP_L_NAME . ($config_fields['l_name']['require']) ? '<span>*</span>' : '' ?>
      <input type="text" name="f_name" id="l_name" value="" class="inputbox" />
    </label>
  <?php endif: ?>
  
</div>
```

Comment: вроде, очевидно. что это код плагина joomla, так что комментарии по стилистике кода автору можно не предъявлять.